# Prove that a finite complete graph can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

I've actually found a few intuitive examples where edges are taken to a twisted cubic and and the vertices are arranged in a certain way and that's very nice, but I'm actually more interested in a more straightforward algebraic proof if one exists. For example, showing a finite graph is also a noetherian topological space and then going from there (I'm not even sure that's true). I also came across a proof that used the fact that a finite graph is separable metric space. Basically I would just love to relate this problem in some way to abstract algebra if doable.

Comment: If you're giving it the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the euclidean topology then a graph isn't a noetherian topological space. I think you should try to prove that there is an immersion into the plane where are the intersections of edges are in general position and then you can easily move them apart with an extra dimension.